# Looking for a plant for my appartement

Tags: indoors, plant-recommendations

I already killed a cactus because of mold/ humidity. And a Yucca by lack of sun light.
And I'm looking for a new plant..

The plant will be siting, right next to a window touching the wall. Windows is 40° N-E.
It need to be medium size in order to get the sun. 0.80m > x > 1.60m
The humidity in the room can be quite high as it's a kitchen without ventilation.

Ideally, It will not make my cat explode, doesn't need to be safe or edigible, just not dangerous.

Localisation :  48.40,-4.53, the rainny coast of Britany

Comment: Visual representation of the small space between the wall and the window. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ47D.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some plants that might work in your space and won't make your cat explode. All suggestions and quotes are from [this list of cat-friendly plants](https://www.purewow.com/family/cat-friendly-plants). You'll find photos of the plants there.

### Small trees and shrubs

Hibiscus (*Hibiscus rosa-sinensis, H. syriacus*)

> These beauties have big personalities and about 1,000 colorful options (yep). They also work well both indoors and out, especially if you want to attract hummingbirds or butterflies.

Ponytail Palm (Beaucarnea recurvata)

> These playful plants are major air purifiers. They prefer lower light, so they’re ideal for rooms that need some life but have little sunlight to give.

Bamboo Palm (*Chamaedorea seifrizii*)

> If you’re looking for a luscious plant that can take up a lot of space, look no further. Bamboo Palms grow up to around five feet tall and can turn a bland space into a miniature jungle.

Parlor Palm (*Chamaedorea elegans*)

> Parlor Palms only grow up to two feet tall but these impressive plants feel much larger. They’re like miniature explosions of greenery—and a great compromise between a large bamboo palm and a tiny spider plant.

Majesty Palm (*Ravenea rivularis*)

> A palm from Madagascar that grows several feet tall. Its fronds are also concentrated towards the top of the plant, so even though it’s safe for cats, they’ll have trouble reaching up that high if they want to snack.

Money Tree (*Pachira aquatica*)

> This plant is adorable, stands several feet tall, and gets rid of toxins from cleaning products in the air.

Chinese Palm Plant (*Trachycarpus fortunei*)

> This stunner can grow up to eight feet tall but is less cumbersome than the Bamboo Palm. It’s native to tropical climates, so water accordingly.

Cast Iron Plant (*Aspidistra elatior*)

> This is perhaps the perfect house plant for a cat owner. It requires very little attention (in fact, its name alludes to how much neglect it can handle), adds subtle personality to a room and requires an occasional grooming sesh (wiping down the large green leaves). Remind you of anyone you know?

### Short plants

Calatheas (Calathea orbifolia, C. lancifolia, C. zebrina)

> Low-maintenance, colorful, humidity-loving.

Staghorn Fern (*Platycerium bifurcatum*)

> Some ferns are non-toxic to cats and dogs, while others could be poisonous. That’s why it’s important to check both the common name (like Staghorn Fern) and the scientific name (like P*latycerium bifurcatum*). In terms of maintenance, these guys are pretty easy going—with enough sunlight and water every one to two weeks, these wavy ferns will thrive.

Boston Fern (*Nephrolepis exaltata*)

> The Boston fern is like the BFF you can call at 2 a.m., no questions asked, and they’ll talk as long as you need. In a word: reliable. In two words: natural humidifier.

Bird's Nest Fern (*Asplenium nidus*)

> This crimpy-leaved fern loves indirect sunlight, humidity, and water. It almost looks like a pointier, fancier version of kale, except it won’t harm your cat if she takes a nibble.

Kimberly Queen Fern (*Nephrolepis obliterata*)

> Like royalty, it looks as though the Kimberly Queen Fern is wearing a crown. Unlike royalty, this princess is low maintenance and prefers staying out of the spotlight (i.e., bright sunshine).

Footed Blue Star Fern (*Phlebodium aureum*)

> Like the Blue-Footed Booby, the Footed Blue Star loves to be near water. Keep its soil moist and this robust fern will keep your home smelling fresh (and your cats healthy).

Bromeliad (*Guzmania lingulata*)

> For a plant that’s known for being drought-tolerant, the Bromeliad blooms gorgeous flowers and long leaves. This one loves sunlight and can grow up to 20 inches tall, though there are smaller varieties available.

Peperomia Ginny (*Peperomia clusiifolia*)

> Unassuming in size, the Peperomia Ginny is super resilient and can survive in many different climates making it a great plant for beginners.

Haworthia Zebra (*Haworthiopsis attenuata*)

> These spiky, cacti-looking monsters are perfect alternatives to aloe plants. And they can also go for several weeks without water in case you’re the type of person who tends to forget to take care of your greenery (raises hand).

Neon Prayer Plant (*Maranta leuconeura*)

> Ideal in low to bright indirect sunlight, these striped plants add heaps of personality to a space. In terms of care, don’t ignore them, but don’t hover; they like their independence.

Purple Velvet Plant (*Gynura aurantiaca*)

> The leaves of the purple velvet plant are, you guessed it, a bright plum purple, making it the perfect accessory to your many green house plants. Sometimes, it produces tiny orange flowers, too.

American Rubber Plant (*Peperomia obtusifolia*)

> Not only is the American rubber plant non-toxic to felines, but it literally removes toxins from the air. A little bright sunlight, regular watering and a pot large enough for a four-foot-tall tree (they can grow up to 10 feet!) is all you need. (Be sure to go with the American version, rather than the Indian Rubber Plant, which is actually part of the fig family.)

### Hanging plants and vines

*Probably not ideal for your spot on the floor under a window, but they could work if you're willing to buy a stand*

Air Plants (*Tillandsia* varieties)

> They look delicate but are easy to take care of—just soak them in water every week or two. Experiment with terrariums, hanging planters, and tablescapes to elevate your space.

Spider Plant (*Chlorophytum comosum*)

> Spider plants are the gifts that keep on giving. If they grow too big for their planters and spill over the sides, simply trim them and replant the new clippings. Voila! More plants.